# C2DM registration ID clarification

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am new to C2DM. I have few question about C2DM registration ID.

I have installed same C2DM Mobile app in two devices. Whether I will need two rigistrations ID for two devices or we need one registration ID for mobile client.

My requirement is I have to install client app in two devices and I need to notify both the devices same time when I changed data in Server.

Suggest me the RegistrtionID implementation.

Answer (score 1):

each device can register separately and will receive a separate registration id.  When it's received, you'll send the registration id to your application server.

However the registration id is stored on your server, you'll want to send separate notifications for each device that you want to receive a notification  (as identified by its registration id).

Comment: When I am registering just I am passing Sender name only. I am not specifying any device info right. So the C2DM server will send message to sender registration ID right.

Comment: the registration ID that you receive when the device registers is all you need to send a message to that device from the app server.

Comment: can you tell me in detail, what should application server be or do? or indicate some reference manuals , cause I don't understand what should I do...

Comment: the application server is whatever is sending the notification.  So: the device registers with Apple, and gets a registration id.  The device provides this registration id to your application server.  When the application server wants to send a notification, it sends it to Apple, with the registration id to indicate which device the notification should be sent to.